# Replace all occurrences with only one pattern using sed

Tags: shell, replace, sed

I programmed a shell script to set the GSSAPIAuthentication to no in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

In my script I have this section:

```
if [ $( grep "^GSSAPIAuthentication no$" /etc/ssh/sshd_config >/dev/null; echo $? ) -ne 0 ]; then
    sed -i 's/^[#]*GSSAPIAuthentication.*$/GSSAPIAuthentication no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
fi
```

This works fine, but it replaces all occurences to:

#GSSAPIAuthentication no --> GSSAPIAuthentication no

#GSSAPIAuthentication yes --> GSSAPIAuthentication no

GSSAPIAuthentication yes --> GSSAPIAuthentication no

So I have multiple lines with GSSAPIAuthentication no. How can I change this to have only one line with GSSAPIAuthentication no?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using awk to do this:

```
awk '/GSSAPIAuthentication/ { if (!seen++) print "GSSAPIAuthentication no"; next } 1' file
```

This replaces the first instance of a line containing "GSSAPIAuthentication" with the desired replacement. For subsequent lines matching the pattern, `!seen++` will be true, so they are not printed and `next` skips to the next record. The `1` at the end is always true so other lines are printed.

To overwrite the existing file, use the standard pattern `awk '...' /etc/ssh/sshd_config > tmp && mv tmp /etc/ssh/sshd_config` (but I'd save doing that until you've established that you're happy with the result).